# Using regex to extract index of the element from the list and retrieve value

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings, below is just one example:

```
str_list = ['Navitas', 'Organic Cacao Powder', '227g', 'SALE $7.49 ea', 'Regular $9:99-ea', 'Valid 01/12 - 01/18']
```

I want to extract the '227g' element based on finding the index.

```
unit_index = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(str_list) if val.endswith((' ml','-pack','{\d}g', ' L'))]
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I would like to find out where it ends with a digit **followed** by a unit of measure (ml, g, L)

Comment: Maybe just filter with `re.search(r'(?: ml|-pack|\d+g)$', val)`? Or see https://ideone.com/L3xL1L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\d+\s?(ml|-pack|g|L)$` to check for a number with a unit after it.

```py
import re

str_list = ['Navitas', 'Organic Cacao Powder', '227g', 'SALE $7.49 ea', 'Regular $9:99-ea', 'Valid 01/12 - 01/18']
r = r"\d+\s?(ml|-pack|g|L)$"
unit_index = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(str_list) if re.search(r, val)][0]
```